# How to copy the html contents of one iframe to another iframe including CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, styles

i am writing a HTML webPage which contains two iframes, say iframeA and iframeB.
Frequently i need to copy the HTML contents of  iframeA into HTML contents of iframeB using JavaScript.
Using **document.body.innerHTML** property I can copy the contents but i have no idea. How to copy the style(CSS) attribute of each element of iframeA into iframeB ?

Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. 
i used `<div>` tag inside `<body>` tag in both iframes' html. So my iframe HTML contents are within `<div>` tag as bellow:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id = "mydiv">
  //Body contents
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

then i used **importNode()** and **replaceChild()** API to replace `<div>` node of iframeB with `<div>` node of iframeA. This will handle all the HTML elements and its style under `<div>` tag. No need to iterate each element to check and copy the style.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery's .css() can do this:
http://api.jquery.com/css/

For instance, you can do something along the lines of:

```
function copyCss() {
   var iframeABackgroundColor = $('#iframeAElementID').css("background-color");
   $('#iframeBElementID').css("background-color", iframeABackgroundColor); }
```

JSFiddle demonstrating the concept: https://jsfiddle.net/xbdk0jy9/1/

Comment: Note that you need to include the JQuery API in your page for this to work, by adding `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js">` to your `<head>` tags

Comment: Does this not answer the question? Instead of simply downvoting, please give some feedback so that I can work on the problems you have with my answer :)

Comment: i didn't downvote ur answer. i m not denying your answer. But i wanted to do it all changes at once.

Comment: Yes, neither did I assume that it was you :) It was simply directed at whoever downvoted it. I apologise for the confusion.